# What's the Ruby equivalent of Python's os.walk?

Tags: python, ruby

Does anyone know if there's an existing module/function inside Ruby to traverse file system directories and files?  I'm looking for something similar to Python's `os.walk`. The closest module I've found is `Find` but requires some extra work to do the traversal.

The Python code looks like the following:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        print name
    for name in dirs:
        print name
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following will print all files recursively. Then you can use File.directory? to see if the it is a directory or a file.

```
Dir['**/*'].each { |f| print f }
```

Comment: Instead of `Dir[foo].each { bar }`, you can use `Dir.glob(foo) { bar }` which will iterate over all the files matching the block without creating a temporary array first.

Comment: Is `Dir.foreach('.') { |f| print f } ` the same?  It looks more expressive than the [] version.

Comment: @Thierry: No. Dir.foreach does not enter subdirectories.

Comment: I like the glob, you can cherry pick the files you want

Answer (score 11):

[Find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) seems pretty simple to me:

```
require "find"
Find.find('mydir'){|f| puts f}
```

Comment: And where is `Find` defined? `require "find"`

Here is the docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html

Answer (score 5):

```
require 'pathname'

def os_walk(dir)
  root = Pathname(dir)
  files, dirs = [], []
  Pathname(root).find do |path|
    unless path == root
      dirs << path if path.directory?
      files << path if path.file?
    end
  end
  [root, files, dirs]
end

root, files, dirs = os_walk('.')
```