# Ruby Dir.glob alternative with Regexp

Tags: ruby, filepath, glob, dir

Ruby's `Dir.glob` accepts a glob String that has some regular expression behaviour, but it doesn't have the full abilities of `Regexp`.

What alternatives in Ruby (including core and gems) are there to `Dir.glob` that allow the use of `Regexp` to match file paths?

Comment: You may be able to use `Find` to walk directories and do a regex against them [?] http://stackoverflow.com/a/1281222/32453

Comment: [The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) says it clearly: "Note that this pattern is not a regexp, it's closer to a shell glob." Consider it like you would a pattern to a `ls` at the command-line.

Comment: [Find](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/index.html) is an excellent, though underused, way to walk a directory hierarchy. Using regexp with Dir and Find is easy done using `select` and `reject` to find matches, or within blocks using `next` or `prune`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thing with glob is that it can match subpaths. When you write `Dir.glob('*/*')` it'll return all the files and directories directly under subdirectories of the current directories. It can do that because glob patterns are simple enough for the computer to understand - if it was regex it would have to scan the entire filesystem and compare each path with the pattern, which is simply too much.

However, you can combine - use `Dir.glob` to choose **where** to search, and `grep` to choose **what** to search:

```
[1] pry(main)> Dir.glob('/usr/lib/*').grep(/\/lib[A-Z]+\.so$/)
=> ["/usr/lib/libFLAC.so", "/usr/lib/libEGL.so", "/usr/lib/libHACD.so", "/usr/lib/libLTO.so", "/usr/lib/libGLEW.so", "/usr/lib/libGL.so", "/usr/lib/libSDL.so", "/usr/lib/libGLU.so", "/usr/lib/libSM.so", "/usr/lib/libICE.so"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Although full regex isn't supported, you can do tricks like the following in glob

```
Dir.glob("folder_with_images/*.{jpg,png}")
```

Comment: I used this to do `Dir.glob("test/models/#{model}{/*_test.rb,_test.rb}` to find `test/model/abc_test.rb` as well as `test/model/abc/my_sub_test.rb`