# What's the Ruby equivalent of Python's os.walk(path, topdown=false)?

Tags: python, ruby

This is similar to [What's the Ruby equivalent of Python's os.walk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281090/whats-the-ruby-equivalent-of-pythons-os-walk), but I'm interested in walking the directory tree from the leaves back, rather than the root out.

I.e., for a directory structure like

```
/root/
|- A/
   |- a.txt
|- B/
   |- b.txt
   |- C/
      |- c.txt
```

Given `root`, I'd like to traverse it in the following order.

1. /root/A/a.txt
2. /root/A
3. /root/B/C/c.txt
4. /root/B/C
5. /root/B/b.txt
6. /root/B

I need to replace file content and rename both files and directories during the traversal, so variations on that order would be OK.  Because of the directory renaming, starting at the root directory isn't an attractive option.

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498539/searching-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-for-files-of-a-certain-type)?

Comment: @tadman The accepted answer on that question points to the Find module, whose documentation says it “supports the top-down traversal of a set of file paths.” OP is asking for the opposite: Bottom-up traversal.

Comment: It might work if you just reverse the list of what you find. Depends! There's a few options explored there.

Comment: https://github.com/samonzeweb/walk

Comment: Out of interest, what do you expect/want to happen if there was *also* a folder `/root/B/D` containing text files - are you expecting to start from C, then find the *sibling* directory?

Comment: @NeilSlater, yes, siblings all the way down.  I've added to the example directory hierarchy to clarify that.

Comment: @Casper, that looks promising.  Any reason you didn't make it a full-fledged answer instead of a comment?

Comment: If it does what you need perhaps write it as an answer and accept? I'll upvoat.

Answer (score 0):

Although I originally wrote my own solution to this (included below), I like [Casper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823617)'s suggestion, http://github.com/samonzeweb/walk, better since it behaves *exactly* as `os.walk(x, topdown=false)` does in Python.

My original solution follows.  It's usage differs from `os.walk()` because it yields individual file and directory paths, rather than a tuple of `(path, subdirs, files)`.

```
def bottomup_path_walk(dir, &block)
  files = []
  subdirs = []
  Dir.glob(File.join(dir, "*")).each do |path_str|
    path = Pathname.new(path_str)
    if path.directory?
      bottomup_path_walk(path, &block)
      subdirs << path
    elsif path.file?
      files << path
    end
  end

  files.each   { |f| yield f }
  subdirs.each { |d| yield d }
end
```

Given the directory tree in the question, the preceding code traverses in this order (which is safe for renaming both files and directories).

1. /root/B/C/c.txt
2. /root/B/b.txt
3. /root/B/C
4. /root/B/b.txt
5. /root/A/a.txt
6. /root/A
7. /root/B